# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: sql, syntax

Всем привет! Не могу создать таблицу:

```
    CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `start_time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `end_time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `active` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `game_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reward` decimal(13,2) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(13,2) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2016-11-08 21:32:40.000000',
  `updated_at` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2022-11-08 21:32:40.000000'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Ошибка:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2016-11-08 21:32:40.000000', `updated_at` timestamp(6) ' at line 10

Остальные таблицы из дампа заливал и поправлял вот так, но с этой таблицей не могу разобраться

Пример:

```
    CREATE TABLE `subscriptions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `json` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Я заливал вот так и ошибок не было:

```
    CREATE TABLE `subscriptions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `json` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Код валидный. Проверяй на наличие неотображаемых символов. В конце концов удали и перенабери руками `timestamp(6)`.

Comment: Пробовал, все тоже самое

Answer (score 0):

Вроде разобрался. Заменил TIMESTAMP на DATETIME и все создалось